# Google App Engine python loop not working

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, loops, substring

I just don't understand why this doesn't work...
Please help

In my database I have an assignment class
every assignment has a name property and a tags property

Basically I am trying to make a search results that sees if a search term(a substring) is in the name or tag of anything in the datastore

```
    #Here I pull out all of the Assignments from the assignment class
    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment ORDER BY created DESC")
    #Here I make a results list, to store the finished assignments in
    results = []
    #This is a loop to go through all terms of the search
    for t in terms:
        #Here is a loop to go through all assignments per search term
        for r in res:
            #Here is why in the world does this not work...
            #If I change it to "if 'd' in 'dog' and t not in results:",
            #then it works....
            #but even when t is 'a' and r.name is 'aaa' it doesn't work
            if t in r.name and t not in results:
                results.append(r)
            if r.tags:
                if t in r.tags and t not in results:
                    results.append(r)
    print results
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have the `t` and `r` mixed up in the code. You either want to check and store `r` to collect matching assignments:

```
for t in terms:
    for r in res:
        if t in r.name and r not in results:
            results.append(r)
        if r.tags:
            if t in r.tags and r not in results:
                results.append(r)
```

or the other way around, check and store `t` to collect matched search terms:

```
for t in terms:
    for r in res:
        if t in r.name and t not in results:
            results.append(t)
        if r.tags:
            if t in r.tags and t not in results:
                results.append(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if t in r.name and r not in results:
   results.append(r)
if r.tags:
   if t in r.tags and r not in results:
     results.append(r)
```